# Is there a git indicator to get notification on commit, pull?

Tags: software-recommendation, indicator, notification, git

Is there an indicator for watching a git repository and get notification on commit, push, ... ?

Searching "indicator ubuntu git watch repository" send me a lot of indicator hosted on github... can't find anything usefull for this...

Comment: Use [zapier](https://zapier.com/‎).Register for a free zapier account. Authorize zapier for github account. Authorize twitter account. Get commit, push.....etc notification through twitter.Use polly or birdie twitter client on Ubuntu.Or you can use email notification.

Comment: Another option is to use [git-dude](https://github.com/sickill/git-dude). But its buggy on 13.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a little python program that does what you're looking for. It's a bit rough around the edges, so I'd appreciate any feedback you might have.

[ubuntu git indicator](https://github.com/itsadok/git-indicator)

To use it, run git-indicator from a directory that contains one or more git repositories (like you'd use git-dude).

Example:

```
~$ git clone https://github.com/itsadok/git-indicator.git ~/.git-indicator
~$ cd ~/repos
~/repos$ ls
repo1 repo2 repo3
~/repos$ ~/.git-indicator/git-indicator.py &
```

Comment: git-dude looks on --mirror repository and I can't use "git status -b --porcelain" on a mirror. I'm forking your git repo and have a look later. It can be a good start, thanks :)

Comment: @SpiderWan if you have the time, contact me on gmail. I'd love to have a chat about this.

Comment: Can't find your gmail address. You can contact me on mail@ my domain (website on my profil)

Comment: Here is my "clone" : https://github.com/NaWer/indicator-git/tree/develop

Answer (score 8):

I think what you want is git-dude.

## git-dude

https://github.com/sickill/git-dude

git-dude is a simple git desktop notifier. It monitors git repositories in
current directory for new commits/branches/tags and shows desktop notification if
anything new arrived.

### How it works

It simply uses `git fetch` and parses its output to see what has changed. Then it
formats new commit messages with `git log` and shows desktop notification with
`notify-send` / `kdialog` (Linux) or `growlnotify` (OSX). All of this in infinite loop.

### How does it look

Fedora (Gnome-Shell) :

[image: git-dude on Fedora]

Ubuntu:

[image: git-dude on Ubuntu]

### Requirements

On Linux:

- `notify-send` on Gnome (Fedora: *libnotify* package, Ubuntu: *libnotify-bin* package)
- `kdialog` on KDE (included in KDE)

On OSX:

- `growlnotify`, from [Growl Extras](http://growl.info/extras.php#growlnotify)
  (Homebrew: *growlnotify* package)

### Installation

```
$ curl -skL https://github.com/sickill/git-dude/raw/master/git-dude >~/bin/git-dude
$ chmod +x ~/bin/git-dude
```

* Make sure `~/bin` is in your `$PATH` or put `git-dude` script somewhere else
on your `$PATH`.

### Usage

git-dude iterates over repositories that live inside *the dude directory*. This
directory is nothing more than container for cloned repositories of projects
you want to watch.  Name it like you want, here for example we use
*~/.git-dude*:

```
$ mkdir ~/.git-dude
$ cd ~/.git-dude
```

Clone some repositories:

```
$ git clone --mirror https://github.com/joelthelion/autojump.git
$ git clone --mirror git://github.com/pyromaniac/hoof.git
```

I recommend `git clone --mirror` - it doesn't checkout working directory so it
saves some disk space for bigger projects.

Symlinked repositories work too. This way you can monitor already cloned
projects:

```
$ ln -s ~/code/tmuxinator .
```

Now run this to monitor *pwd*:

```
$ git dude
```

You can also pass directory name as first argument to specify which directory
to monitor instead of *pwd*.

```
$ git dude ~/watched-repos
```

This way you can have multiple *dude directories* each being monitored by
separate git-dude process.

### Configuration

#### Global

Set how often git-dude should check for changes (in seconds, default: 60):

```
$ git config --global dude.interval 30
```

Set path to icon used by desktop notifications (default: none):

```
$ git config --global dude.icon ~/.git-dude/github_32.png
```

Set custom notification command (`$TITLE`, `$DESCRIPTION` and `$ICON_PATH`
environment variables are set when invoking notification command):

```
$ git config --global dude.notify-command 'gntp-send "$TITLE" "$DESCRIPTION" "$ICON_PATH"'
$ git config --global dude.notify-command 'echo -e "$TITLE\n\n\n$DESCRIPTION" | espeak --stdin -k20 -ven+12'
```

#### Per-repository

Set path to icon used by desktop notifications for this repository (default:
taken from global setting):

```
$ git config dude.icon ~/.git-dude/dm-core/datamapper.png
```

Tell git-dude to ignore specific repository (if you want to *unmonitor* it):

```
$ git config dude.ignore true
```

### Author

Marcin Kulik (http://ku1ik.com/ | @sickill)

---

To track notifications use [Recent Notifications indicator](https://launchpad.net/~jconti/+archive/recent-notifications).

[image: screenshot recent notifications]

In a terminal run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jconti/recent-notifications
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-notifications
```

After installing run <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> `unity --replace`.

You will find a little mailbox in the panel:
[image: recent notifications in panel]]

Comment: So much to like about this answer. Bonus points for the recent-notifications indicator plug and recycling unity's UI command.